# How to prove that Pi exists?

Tags: geometry, pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that Pi is constant (the same for all circles), without using limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/proof-that-pi-is-constant-the-same-for-all-circles-without-using-limits)

How do we prove that the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter is a certain real number, the same for any circle (which we call pi)?
Is there a pure geometric proof that the ratio is always the same?

Comment: Hand waving answer: it is a ratio, and ratios are constant with scaling. Making a bigger or smaller circle is just scaling, so the ratio stays the same.

Comment: Is a simple scaling argument not acceptable?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/why-is-euclidean-geometry-scale-invariant) is also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

One way to introduce lengths into Euclidean geometry is to use Rene Descartes' co-ordinate geometry. In this setup, using the methods of calculus, you can prove the said result using integration to compute the circumference(with an integral for the length of a curve).